# Is it possible to access the auditLog data? e.g. how can active users be monitored?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspnet boilerplate react.

Everything works as expected. Tenants, controllers, even odata controllers are working fine now. Every controller writes a audit data for its entity. But I am interrested now to get access to this audit data. On the database side, the data is written to tables like auditLog and as additional columns per entity table.

How to access the audit data? Collecting works fine. But not idea how to access it and show in frontend.

My attempts like
AsyncCrudAppService<AuditLog, AuditedEntityDto, long, PagedResultRequestDto, AuditedEntityDto, AuditedEntityDto>

or writing a odata controllers didnt work.

Comment: odata controllers didnt compile or produced errors because the dto files are missing. The AsyncCrudAppService above produced internal errors handling a http get. Any ideal how it should look like?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Users)]
[DisableAuditing]
public class AuditLogAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<AuditLog, 
AuditedEntityDto<long>, long, PagedResultRequestDto, 
AuditedEntityDto<long>, AuditedEntityDto<long>>
{
    public AuditLogAppService(
        IRepository<AuditLog, long> repository,
        UserManager userManager,
        RoleManager roleManager,
        IRepository<Role> roleRepository,
        IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher,
        IAbpSession abpSession,
        LogInManager logInManager)
        : base(repository)
    {

    }

    public Task<ListResultDto<AuditLog>> GetAllAudits()
    {

        object audits = Repository.GetAll();

        return Task.FromResult(new ListResultDto<AuditLog>(
            ObjectMapper.Map<List<AuditLog>>(audits).ToList()
        ));

    }
}
```